# Spring Boot Getting 403 on Error inside the Service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

The following is the implementation of `SecurityFilterChain`:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurity  {
    private final UserService userDetailsService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurity(UserService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder =
                http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);

        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);

        http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

And the `UserService` implementation looks like this:

```java
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private Utils utils;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserDto createUser(UserDto userDto) {
        UserEntity exists = userRepository.findByEmail(userDto.getEmail());

        if(exists != null){
            throw new RuntimeException("Record already exists" );
        }

        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(userDto, userEntity);

        String publicUserId = utils.generateUserId(30);
        userEntity.setUserId(publicUserId);
        userEntity.setEncryptedPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()));

        UserEntity storedUserEntity = userRepository.save(userEntity);

        UserDto returnValue = new UserDto();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(storedUserEntity, returnValue);
        return returnValue;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
        if(userEntity == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        return new User(username, userEntity.getEncryptedPassword(), new ArrayList<>());
    }
}
```

Now, I am able to create new users via `/users` endpoint. However, if I try to create the user with existing email, then I am getting 403 error. I was expecting a error with stacktrace. Why 403?

[image]

Comment: You can enable logs at the root level. I guess it's throwing an error because /error might not be mapped.  Can you add /error also in permitAll and try?

Comment: I added `/error` its now showing the proper error message. But why it is happening in the first place? and how to prevent it?

Comment: When you are throwing RunTimeException, it's trying to render it on `/error`. Now, you have only allowed `/users` endpoint for all. Hence, your application is not authorized to show the error page. That's why it's throwing 403.

Comment: I think `anyRequest().authenticated()` this is the line causing the issue.

Comment: Absolutely. That's what I meant to say that you've only allowed the `/users` endpoint for all. For the rest of the endpoints, you'll need to authenticate. That's the purpose of `anyRequest().authenticated()`

Comment: Welcome. I recently learned spring-security. I'm glad that I was able to help. :)

Comment: @ankush__ can u please share the resource you used to learn it.

Comment: the resource is the standard spring boot documentation, its in the first sentance in the chapter named _Error Handling_ https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.error-handling a suggestion is to read docs on error handling

Comment: @cody add  please in your question your UserDetailsService and also your relevant controller

Comment: @Cody I read the documentation. More importantly, I enabled the logging level to debug which helped me to understand the flow.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen due to securityconfiguration class is not added in springboot 3 , websecurityconfigureadaptor is deprecated so you cant use old definition of class .

Below bean definition can be used instead of overriding configure method from websecurityconfigureadaptor

https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter